# Unexpected identifier in JSON Eval function

Tags: javascript, json, syntax, eval

heres the code i've copied somewhere for rating a page. This codes works fine on my localhost yet when I upload it on the server It returns a syntax error.

```
 function rtgAjax(elm, ratev) {
   var cerere_http =  get_XmlHttp();        // get XMLHttpRequest object

 // define data to be send via POST to PHP (Array with name=value pairs)
  var datasend = Array();
  for(var i=0; i<elm.length; i++) datasend[i] = 'elm[]='+elm[i];
     // joins the array items into a string, separated by '&'
     datasend = datasend.join('&')+'&rate='+ratev;

     cerere_http.open("POST", 'ratingfiles/ratings.php', true);         
       //     crate the request

  cerere_http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");              // header for POST
  cerere_http.send(datasend);       
 //  make the ajax request, poassing the data

 // checks and receives the response
 cerere_http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (cerere_http.readyState == 4) {
  // receives a JSON with one or more item:['totalrate', 'nrrates', renot]
  eval(' var jsonitems = ' + cerere_http.responseText);

  // if jsonitems is defined variable
  if (jsonitems) {
    // parse the jsonitems object
    for(var rtgitem in jsonitems) {
      var renot = jsonitems[rtgitem][2];        
  // determine if the user can rate or not

      // if renot=3 displaies alert that already voted, else, continue with the rating reactualization
       if(renot == 3) {
        alert("You already voted \n You can rate again tomorrow");
        window.location.reload(true);       // Reload the page
      }
      else addRtgData(rtgitem, jsonitems[rtgitem][0], jsonitems[rtgitem][1], renot);    // calls function that shows rating
    }
  }
```

this line,

```
 eval(' var jsonitems = ' + cerere_http.responseText);
```

returns a Syntax error: Unexpected Identifier

Comment: You should show what value is going in `cerere_http.responseText`

Comment: `responseText` must not be valid JSON. Also, as you are probably aware, eval() is pretty dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` should not be used in this way. Instead, try this:

```
var jsonitems;
try {
    jsonitems = JSON.parse(cerere_http.responseText);
}
catch(e) {alert("Failed to parse JSON: "+e);}
```

Comment: returns Unexpected token U

Comment: That indicates that your JSON is invalid. Try outputting it and see what you get.

Comment: Note: If you must support IE7, JSON.parse is not supported.  So you might want to look into a polyfill, such as Crockford's [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).  As @Kolink stated though, it is clear that your response is not valid JSON anyway, so that's your first and primary problem.